# Understanding javascript this scoping - with a simple Backbone example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, closures, this

Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yec2h/15/)

Code also listed below:

```
window.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

ticks: 0,
initialize: function() {
    //window.setInterval(this.onTimerTick, 1000); // arghhh.. can't understand the 'this' scoping       
    window.setInterval(this.onTimerTick2, 1000);  // Works great with globals       
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.text(this.ticks);            
},

onTimerTick: function() {  // Trouble with this
    this.ticks++;
    this.render();
},

onTimerTick2: function() {  // Using globals
    window.ticks2++;
    $('#count').text(window.ticks2);
}
});

window.My = new MyView({ el: $("#count") });
window.ticks2 = 0;
```

Looking at the code, you see I would like to use the onTimerTick function, but becouse I can't figure out how to get from the window-this to the My-this, I must use the approach seen in onTimerTick2. (usually I get around with a that=this, but in this case it is not enough)

Thanks for any attemt to make me understand this(!)

Thanks

Larsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing `this.onTimerTick2` to setTimeout, the function will be called with `this` being bound to the global object, not your object.

If underscore.js is available (according to @ori it is), you can use `_.bind()` to lock `this` to the correct object when called:

```
window.setInterval(_.bind(this.onTimerTick, this), 1000);
```

Here are some solutions that do not depend on a library:

```
// Works in all browsers
var self = this;
window.setInterval(function() {
    self.onTimerTick();
}, 1000);
```

With a modern JS engine you can also use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to keep the correct `this`:

```
// Requires a modern JS engine
window.setInterval(this.onTimerTick.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: Not me! I'm very happy for all suggestions :-) Thanks for providing a good answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like backbone uses the [bind](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind) function from underscore, so:

```
 window.setInterval(_.bind(this.onTimerTick2, this), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also rely to `_.bindAll` utility method, to keep code cleaner and reusable.

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'myFunction')
    setInterval(this.myFunction, 1000)
},

myFunc: function() {
    console.log(this)
}
```